# Electric flux thorugh a closed surface

Tags: electrostatics

A closed surface immersed in a uniform electric field will have zero flux through it. Is there any exception to this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no".

If you put a Gaussian surface, which has no changes within it, into any electric field, the total flux through the Gaussian surface will be zero.